# VB.Net Printing and Page Margins

Tags: vb.net

I am printing a receipt with the following code:

```
Dim printFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 10, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular)
e.Graphics.DrawString(sPrintText, printFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 6)
```

sPrintText is a string I put together that looks like a basic receipt like this:

http://freeurl.ws/original.jpg

I then save the string to a txt file like this:

```
Dim f As New IO.StreamWriter(filename, False)
f.WriteLine(texttoprint)
```

When I open the file in notepad and print it, it comes out like this:

http://freeurl.ws/reprint.jpg

Anyone have any ideas on how I prevent this? I need it to reprint the same way the original did.

Comment: Have you tried another text editor?  Wordpad?  Textpad?

Comment: I've never seen a string reproduce a signature before.  No idea what kind of magic is going on here.  I'd suggest File + Page Setup in notepad.

Comment: LOL um.. that's a scanned image after it has been printed! Only the magic of a scanner. It was scanned to show what happens AFTER it prints...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem using Star Impact Printer, spend over two days using all codes. At end resolve it by using RawPrinterHelper class available from Microsoft.
Here is the code which I have used to open the cash Drawer attached to the printer.
  s = Chr(&H7); 
  RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(receiptprinter, s);
You can substitute s for the full Receipt text. It should do graphics as well , but I have not tried it.

Comment: When I get a minute I'll will give that a shot. Thanks for replying with your resolve.